# Прокрутка по оси x

Tags: html, css

Можно ли при помощи CSS сделать ось X для body основной при прокрутке?

Comment: https://webformyself.com/gorizontalnaya-prokrutka-na-chistom-css/

Answer (score 2):

Создайте блок div с множеством дочерних элементов.

В нашем примере прокручиваемый контейнер будет 300px шириной, в нем будет 8 элементов 100х100px. Размеры произвольные, можно задать любые.

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper squares">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
  <div>item 8</div>
</div>
```

Высота контейнера станет шириной и наоборот. Ниже «ширина» контейнера будет составлять 300px:

```
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

И дочерние элементы:

```
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Теперь нужно повернуть контейнер на -90 градусов при помощи CSS свойства transform. Мы получили горизонтальный скроллер.

```
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  ...
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

Теперь нужно вернуть элементы на свое место. Поверните его обратно при помощи CSS свойства transform.

```
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div {
  ...
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

Первого элемента не видно, так как та же проблема наблюдается и с дочерними элементами. Это можно поправить, задав первому дочернему элементу верхний margin со значением его ширины или трансформировав все элементы, как контейнер. Самый простой способ, это добавить верхний padding к контейнеру, равный ширине дочерних элементов, тем самым создав буферную зону для элементов.

```
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  ...
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
  ...
}
```

Текст скопирован с [сайта](https://webformyself.com/gorizontalnaya-prokrutka-na-chistom-css/)

Comment: Судя по всему, материал на том сайте не опубликован под свободной лицензией. Поэтому сюда просто так его копировать - как-то не айс ((

Comment: @mymedia Я добавил ссылку на оригинал. Если попросят удалить, удалим конечно.